# ACPI not running custom script on power button press

Tags: 14.04, acpi

Any idea how I can debug acpid not starting my custom script on modified xfce4 environment. I've modified "/etc/acpi/events/powerbtn" to point to the correct script:

```
event=button[ /]power
action=/etc/acpi/my-acpi-script
```

Comment: Perhaps this will help: [14.04 no powerbtn action with acpid anymore?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218671&s=1aa7a7936b8bcd0bad51230f4f4c435e)

Comment: Thanks @tuknutx, youre right i got it to work by having logind ignore the event, and rewding from the acpid socket

Answer (score 1):

As the post that @tuknutx mentions says, acpid no longer handles  power button events. They're now handled by systemd's logind . I was quite surprised by this because I had assumed that Ubuntu wasn't using systemd components this release.